# Can someone explain the logic of my code in color depth processing?

Tags: c#, image-processing, colors, pascal

This piece of code was converted from my own Pascal code written in 1999 for handling the .ICO viewer....
It actually reduce the color depth from 256-color downto 16-color.

The following is in C#:

I barely understand the logic behind the code now, that I could not explain it to GitHub readers what is this essential part is about for my Image to (colorful)ASCII converter....

What I know is it takes RGB values and return (16-color)color code (ConsoleColor in C#). I need further help in understanding it.

It might have something to do with the strange Pascal way of evaluating condition and nested iteration construct....

```
static int SimplifyColorComponent(int Value)
{
   if (Value >= 52)
       return 63;
   else if (Value >= 32)
       return 42;
   else if (Value >= 12)
       return 21;

   return 0;
}

static byte DecreaseColor256(byte Red, byte Green, byte Blue)
{
   byte[,] Palette16 = new byte[16,3] { {0, 0, 0 }, {0, 0, 42 }, {0, 42, 0 }, {0, 42, 42 }, { 42, 0, 0 }, {42, 0, 42}, {42, 42, 0}, {42, 42, 42}, { 0, 0, 21}, {0, 0, 63}, {0, 42, 21}, {0, 42, 63}, { 42, 0, 21}, { 42, 0, 63}, { 42, 42, 21}, { 42, 42, 63} };

   byte Color;
   byte Component;
   byte Value = 0;
   byte NewRed = 0;
   byte NewGreen = 0;
   byte NewBlue = 0;

   for (Component = 0; Component <= 2; Component++)
   {
       if (Component == 0)
           Value = (byte)SimplifyColorComponent(Red / 4);
       else if (Component == 1)
           Value = (byte)SimplifyColorComponent(Green / 4);
       else if (Component == 2)
           Value = (byte)SimplifyColorComponent(Blue / 4);

       Color = 0;

       while (Value != Palette16[Color, Component])
       {
           Color++;

           if (Color > 15)
           {
               Value -= 21;
               Color = 0;
           }
       }

       if (Component == 0)
           NewRed = Value;
       else if (Component == 1)
           NewGreen = Value;
       else if (Component == 2)
           NewBlue = Value;

   }

   for (Color = 0; Color <= 15; Color++)
       if ((Palette16[Color, 0] == NewRed) && (Palette16[Color, 1] == NewGreen) && (Palette16[Color, 2] == NewBlue))
           return Color;

   return 0;
}
```

Converted line by line from my legacy Pascal code:

```
function SimplifyColorComponent(Value:byte):byte;
begin
 if Value>=52 then
   SimplifyColorComponent:=63
 else
 if Value>=32 then
   SimplifyColorComponent:=42
 else
 if Value>=12 then
   SimplifyColorComponent:=21
 else
   SimplifyColorComponent:=0;
end;

function DecreaseColor256(Red,Green,Blue:byte):byte;
const
 Palette16:array [0..15,1..3] of byte=((0,0,0),(0,0,42),(0,42,0),(0,42,42),
                                       (42,0,0),(42,0,42),(42,42,0),(42,42,42),
                                       (0,0,21),(0,0,63),(0,42,21),(0,42,63),
                                       (42,0,21),(42,0,63),(42,42,21),(42,42,63));
var
 Color,Component,Value:byte;
 NewRed,NewGreen,NewBlue:byte;

begin
 DecreaseColor256:=0;
 Component:=1;

 repeat
   case Component of
     1:Value:=SimplifyColorComponent(Red div 4);
     2:Value:=SimplifyColorComponent(Green div 4);
     3:Value:=SimplifyColorComponent(Blue div 4);
   end;

   Color:=0;

   while Value<>Palette16[Color,Component] do
   begin
     Inc(Color);

     if Color>15 then
     begin
       Dec(Value,21);
       Color:=0;
     end;
   end;

   case Component of
     1:NewRed:=Value;
     2:NewGreen:=Value;
     3:NewBlue:=Value;
   end;

   Inc(Component);

 until Component>3;

 for Color:=0 to 15 do
   if (Palette16[Color,1]=NewRed) and (Palette16[Color,2]=NewGreen)
   and (Palette16[Color,3]=NewBlue) then
   begin
     DecreaseColor256:=Color;
     Exit;
   end;
end;
```

Comment: Can you describe a bit more in detail what the program's output shall be or how and for what it's being used?

Comment: Yes, for example, DecreaseColor256(255,255,255) will return 15 (Bright White) color code... Likewise, DecreaseColor256(0,0,0) will return 0 (Black) color code. Anything in between will be a color code from 1..14.... It is being used to render 24-bit image on 16-color console screen.

Comment: Yea, that's exactly what it does. Each color is first reduced to one of 4 values (0, 21, 42 or 63), with a bit odd (or random?) overflow handling. The `Palete16` table contains all combinations of these 4 values (times 3 colors), so that's the mapping that gives you the final result.

Comment: Thanks PMF, so mapping is the keyword. But I am confused with this part: ```while (Value != Palette16[Color, Component])
       {
           Color++;

           if (Color > 15)
           {
               Value -= 21;
               Color = 0;
           }
       }``` Why and how does it do the mapping...?

Comment: That part confuses me as well. It tries to find a color that's in the table. But the table is somewhat incomplete or wrong (it never has 21 in the first entry), so it tries something else. To me, this looks like a hack to camuflage a potential problem with the table.